# Count red pixel in a given image

Tags: java, image-processing, pixel, rgba

I am new to Java and want to count red pixels in a given image. I have below code so far but not sure of what condition to add to check if pixel is red. I have below code so far. Thanks in advance.

```
public static int countRedPixels(Picture v){

    BufferedImage image = (v.getBufferedImage());
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    int redCount = 0;
    int pixelCount = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height ; y++) {

            int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);

            //get rgbs
            //int alpha = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
            int red   = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
            int green = (rgb >>>  8) & 0xFF;
            int blue  = (rgb >>>  0) & 0xFF;

            if (red == 255 && green == 0 && blue == 0 || image.getRGB(x, y) == 0xFFFF0000) {
                redCount++;
            }

            pixelCount++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Red Pixel Count:" + redCount);
    System.out.println("Pixel Count:" + pixelCount);
    return redCount;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of *red*? Would it be rgb(255,0,0)?

Comment: Yes, it would be (255,0,0).

Comment: Well, then... `if (red == 255 && green == 0 && blue == 0) { ++redCount; }`? Or even `if (rgb == 0xFFFF0000) ...`

Comment: Ahh! that makes sense. But I wasnt sure if my code that I have written so far is correct or not. I was running it with a sample picture and I get all the values as 255.

Comment: The code we can see here looks fine to me.

Comment: You would want to post the picture you are working with so that we can test it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something or you're really not seeing the forest for the trees. Anyway, comment turned answer:

Given that *red* means (255, 0, 0), you could do:

```
if (image.getRGB(x, y) == 0xFFFF0000) {
    ++redCount;
}
```

Or alternatively, if you don't care about alpha:

```
if (red == 255 && green == 0 && blue == 0) {
    ++redCount;
}
```

Comment: My count is coming as 0 at the end of the function. Which is why I am confused if I did anything wrong in the code I pasted above.

Comment: Does it end up as `0` with both of these approaches?

Comment: Yes. I just changed the image with png one and it worked. Weird that its not working for jpegs.

Comment: That does surprise me, as jpg support should be built-in (assuming you're using `ImageIO` and `BufferedImage`). Oh well, at least it does work now.

Comment: I just edited the code more above. Please see. I am using below image right now. https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/gamedev/images/2x1-rg-post.png

Comment: Also, I am using bmp extension for the images.

Comment: @MilanShah JPEG is a lossy compression, you red will not be (255,0,0), you will have to look in that area.

Comment: Ah, brilliant observation @user1803551. Then again, Milan said that when he used a `jpg`, all of the pixels reported back as (255,255,255), so that's still... weird.

Comment: He didn't give us any such JPEG so no use guessing.